# What should I set max_connections to for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, configuration

I have MySQL 5.1.35 on Linux Centos.  The Linux server has 2GB RAM with 14GB of disk space.

I have created some web services using the Restlet framework in Java that has 1,000+ users.

What should I set `max_connections` to for maximum concurrent connections?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no formula here. You should limit your database according to what you think is reasonable according to your application needs.

Typically, servers with applications using a connection pool shouldn't need more than a few hundred concurrent connections. Small-Medium sized websites may suffice with **100** - **200**.

I usually setup a new server with some **500** - **800** value of `max_connections` and see how it goes. You can always change dynamically via

```
set global max_connections := 567;
```

Make sure, though, you set up a proper `open_files_limit`. On linux, your process is limited to **1024** files, by default. This is very low, since every thread, connection, and, of course, file -- make for a file handle in linux. So set `open_files_limit` to some generous number (say **8192**) to clear up your many connections with the operating system.

I should note I have worked with MySQL servers with thousands of open connections - it's cool. But, most of the time, the vast majority of these connections would sit and do nothing (be idle).

To sum up, I would use what appears to be normal application needs + some threshold for spike events.

Comment: My open_files_limit and max_connections are 1024 and 214 respectively. I want to avoid unix server reboot so i have dynamically changed max_connections to 4000 in mysql. Is this enough  to avoid max_connections issue. Or server reboot is necessary?

Comment: You do not need to reboot the unix server, you will need to restart the mysql daemon.